# Datagrid Alternation Count and Alternationbinding binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

My Xaml view has a datagrid with automatic calculation of the rowindex.

```
<DataGrid MinHeight="600" ColumnWidth="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding List}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedListItem}" AlternationCount="{Binding Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="false" CanUserAddRows="False">
<DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridTextColumn MaxWidth="20" Binding="{Binding AlternationIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}" Header="#"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

**Update**

My ViewModel Snippet:

```
// INPC injected by Fody.Properchanged
   public object SelectedListItem { get; set; }
```

**Question / Problem:**

The AlternationIndex is binded as RelativeSource. How I can get the AlternationIndex binded to a variable in my ViewModel too? I need auomatic generated row index in my ViewModel to work with this value too.

Can I access the AlternationIndex one time by relative source of datagrid and by variable of my viewmodel?

```
// INPC injected by Fody.Properchanged
public int AlternationIndex { get; set; }
```

Comment: and your ViewModel code is ...?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the AlternationIndex property in your view model? This is a read-only property of the DataGridRow, i.e. you have one AlternationIndex per row in your DataGrid.

Comment: I need this indexvalue to write this to my database.